# Close a MySQL connection inside the footer tag

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I wrote in the footer tag my `mysqli_close()` but this footer will appear in pages with no database connections at all. So I tried this:

```
if($connection){
      mysqli_close($connection);
    }
```

but it makes appear a Notice in those pages:

```
! Notice: Undefined variable: connection in ...
```

That's my problem...

Comment: `if(isset($connection))`

Comment: You don't need to close the connection manually. PHP will close it automatically at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Never write any database related code neither in the header nor footer.

Instead, use templates and start any output only when all the database interactions are finished. For this, first store your data from the database in variables, and then pass them in a template.

Comment: Your Common Sense - pls hang around ya - we need your immense expertise ! Its much appreciated !